# get background color of particular text in PDF file

Tags: pdf, colors, itext

how can I find out a particular text's background color (RGB) of a pdf file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No such thing.

The "background color" is just whatever was drawn behind that particular piece of text, if anything.  And text doesn't even have to be text.  It could be an image or paths.

The only thing that MIGHT work would be to render the PDF to pixels (perhaps using GhostScript), and sample pixel colors around where the text is (as determined by iText).  You can determine the fill color at the time the text was painted, so you know what to ignore.

The problem comes when someone places text over something that isn't a solid color.

Doable, but painful.